# Gridview rowcommand after refreshing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview inside an updatepanel.
After updating the gridview, accessing the individual rows does not seem to give the right row.  For example:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = ((e.CommandSource as Control).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
```

Row from the above code gives the values from the gridview before the gridview is refreshed/updated.  Anyone knows how to get the updated values?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to get a row index.

```
e.CommandArgument
```

Here is a good [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx)